# Выполняется ли finally

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Выполняется ли блок finally если будет sendredirect и return?

```java
try {
    response.sendRedirect(session.getAttribute("site") + "/jsp/process/payment.jsp?oid=" + session.getAttribute("OrderID") + "&term=" + session.getAttribute("MerchantID"));
    return;
} finally {

}
```

Comment: Ну, можно было бы и самому проверить. Например чтото напечатать в консоль в блоке finally

Answer (score 8, accepted):

finally не выполняется только в случаях:

1. Вызова `System.exit()`
2. Прерывания текущий потока другим потоком
3. Падения JVM.

```java
public static int getANumber(){
    try{
        return 7;
    } finally {
        return 43;
    }
}
```

Вызов метода `getANumber()` вернет 43.

Comment: а как насчет response.sendRedirect, получается он отрабатывает переводит на другую страницу и потом выполняет finally или finally выполняется до перевода на другую страницу

Comment: @Yeldos а ты сам пробовал в консоль напечатать что-нибудь ? Очень хороший способ для дебага. рекомендую.

Comment: так я же если сделаю переадресацию он же покажет мне другую страницу и мне интересно именно про response.sendredirect

Answer (score 2):

блок `finally` выполняется перед выражением `return`блока `try`
если в блоке `finally` имеется выражение `return`- `return`блока `try` игнорируется

Comment: Имеется в виду, перед возвращением значения? А то ведь код в операторе `return` может и побочные эффекты иметь...

Comment: а насчет response.sendredirect выполняется сначала переадресация или finally

Comment: @YeldosTanikin код блока try выполняется до ключевого слова return( если не кидает исключение). Так что сначала выполняется `response.sendRedirect`

Comment: значит что страница переадресуется и finally тоже выполнится после response а если в finally будет еще response.sendredirect

Answer (score 1):

Единственными моментами, которые, finally, не будут вызываться, являются:

1. Если вы вызываете System.exit();
2. Если сначала произойдет сбой JVM;
3. Если JVM достигает бесконечного цикла (или другого не прерывающегося, не заканчивающегося оператора) в блоке try или catch;
4. Если ОС принудительно завершает процесс JVM; например, "pkill -9" в UNIX.
5. Если хост-система умирает; например, сбой питания, аппаратная ошибка, паника ОС и т.д.
6. Если, наконец, блок будет выполняться потоком демона, а все остальные не-демонные потоки выходят до того, как, наконец, вызывается.

Comment: Перевод гуглтранслейта подредактировать бы надо.